# 'Short-Implement' The Getter 'Long-Implement' The Setter

Tags: c#, getter-setter

For a public primitive variable; is it possible to implement the `set` method and 'Short-Implement' the `get` method?

When I say 'Short-Implement' the `get` I mean:

```
public double width { get; set { width = (isLocked) ? 0:value; } }
```

Instead of 'Long-Implement' the `get`:

```
public double width { get { return width; } set { width = (isLocked) ? 0:value; } }
```

I get a compile error when I attempt to 'Short-Implement' the `get` (whats the term for this btw?) and 'Long-Implement' the `set`. The compile error is:

```
 `Cube.width.get' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

Comment: you can do `private get;`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Not sure that achieves what I want? I want the `get` to be public. I am just lazy and dont want to 'Long-Implement' every `get`

Comment: *is it possible to implement the set method and 'Short-Implement' the get method?* No, it's either 100% auto-property or 0% auto-property. For what it's worth, your `double width { get {...}; set { width = isLocked ? 0 : value; } }` is recursive on all paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to implement the set method and 'Short-Implement' the get method?

No, auto-implemented properties do not allow you to define any part of the getter or setter's implementation.

From [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise **when no additional logic is required** in the property accessors

Use a backing field, and consider treating code that calls your setter when `isLocked` is `true` as erroneous and throwing an exception.

```
set
{
    if (isLocked)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Knock that set off!");

    _width = value;
}
```